# Django NameError: name 'Character' is not defined

Tags: python, django-models

My model is

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

While I make migratation Terminal state that 
"  File "/Users/osx/Desktop/Django Basics 2/Django model relationship/mysite/core/models.py", line 19, in Movie
    characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character)
NameError: name 'Character' is not defined
(myvenv) (base) OSX-MacBook-Pro:mysite osx$ 
"

I dont know where the error come from

Comment: Please do not define two many-to-many relations. Django will automatically construct a relation in reverse, that spans over the same "through" table.

Answer (score 0):

Please do *not* define two many-to-many relations in the two models. If you define a many-to-many field in one of the models. Django will automatically construct the relation in "reverse" in the other model. By defining two many-to-many models, it means that if you add a movie to one of the characters in one of the many-to-many fields, then that character will not appear in the movie you added to that character.

The reason why you get the error is because you *refer* to a class that is, at that point in the code, not yet defined. You can reorder your models, or use a string that contains the name of the model. For example:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # no characters field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    movies = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, related_name='characters')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

By specifying the `related_name='characters'`, we thus specify how Django should name the relation in reverse.